# Open html file with gedit from Unity Dash (Files lens)

Tags: unity-dash, gedit, mime-type, usability

I search a html file wit super-f.

The file was found and Ubuntu displays these choices:

- open folder
- open file
- email file

The above items where translated from german back to english.

If I chosse "open file" the web browser opens.

But I would like to open the file with gedit.

I know that I could open the folder, and then right click to use "open with".

But: Is there no easier way?